# How to reset route params everytime i enter the screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, expo

I have a screen called `Cart` that navigates to another screen called `Checkout` where i have a webview to proccess the payment. According to the url status on this `Checkout` it navigates to the previous screen (`Cart`) sending a paymentStatus inside `params`, so the idea is inside `Cart` i need to display an alert according to the `paymentStatus` received by `params`. To don't get any error when i enter to `Cart` for first time i set `initialParams={{paymentStatus: false}}` on the `Cart` stack screen.

When I enter for first time to `Cart` and pay on `Checkout (Webview)` it send the `paymentStatus` to `Cart` properly and show the alert according to the status received correctly, but if i move to another screen or navigate within the app and later enter to `Cart` again, the `paymentStatus` doesn't change it keeps on the last status sent by my `Checkout`

I have tried using `useState` to store the param received, also using `useEffect` to run my main function(`showPaymentStatus`) that displays the Toast but nothing works, it keeps storing the same `paymentStatus` sent by webview

This is my `Cart`

```js
export default function Cart({ route }) {
  let statusCheckOut = route.params.paymentStatus;
  const [cart, setCart] = useState(null);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(null);
  const [reloadCart, setReloadCart] = useState(false);
  const [addresses, setAddresses] = useState(null);
  const [selectedAddress, setSelectedAddress] = useState(null);
  const [totalPayment, setTotalPayment] = useState(null);
  const { auth } = useAuth();

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      setCart(null);
      setAddresses(null);
      setSelectedAddress(null);

      loadCart();
      loadAddresses();
    }, [])
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    reloadCart && loadCart();
  }, [reloadCart]);

  const loadCart = async () => {
    const response = await getProductCartApi();
    setCart(response);
  };

  const loadAddresses = async () => {
    const response = await getAddressesApi(auth);
    setAddresses(response.data);
    showPaymentStatus();
    navigation.setOptions({ paymentStatus: false });
    statusCheckOut = false;
  };

  const showPaymentStatus = () => {
    if (statusCheckOut) {
      const paymentAttributes = {
        approved: {
          title: "¡It's approved!",
          type: ALERT_TYPE.SUCCESS,
          textBody: "Your payment has been approved",
        },
        rejected: {
          title: "¡Payment rejected!",
          type: ALERT_TYPE.DANGER,
          textBody: "Your payment has been rejected by the bank",
        },
        pending: {
          title: "¡Processing",
          type: ALERT_TYPE.WARNING,
          textBody: "Your payment is pending",
        },
      };
      return Toast.show({
        type: paymentAttributes[statusCheckOut].type,
        title: paymentAttributes[statusCheckOut].title,
        textBody: paymentAttributes[statusCheckOut].textBody,
        autoClose: 3000,
      });
    }
  };
```

This is my `Checkout`

```js
export default function Checkout({ route }) {
  const { url } = route.params;
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  let statusPayment = "none";
  const validatePayment = (status) => {
    const statusUrl = status.url;
    if (statusUrl.includes("/approved/")) {
      statusPayment = "approved";
      navigation.navigate("cart", {paymentStatus: statusPayment});
      return;
    }
    if (statusUrl.includes("/rejected/")) {
      statusPayment = "rejected";
      navigation.navigate("cart", {paymentStatus: statusPayment});
      return;
    }
    if (statusUrl.includes("/recover/")) {
      statusPayment = "pending";
      navigation.navigate("cart", {paymentStatus: statusPayment});
      return;
    }
  };
return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: url }}
          androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled
          javaScriptEnabled
          onLoadProgress={({ nativeEvent }) => validatePayment(nativeEvent)}  
        />
      </View>
    </>
  );
```

Here is where i set the `initialParams` to `Cart`

```js
<Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerTintColor: colors.fontLight,
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: colors.primary },
        cardStyle: {
          backgroundColor: colors.bgLight,
        },
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="cart"
        component={Cart}
        initialParams={{ paymentStatus: false }}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="checkout"
        component={Checkout}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```